# MAE vs MSE for linear regression

Tags: regression, linear-regression, outlier, mse

Several articles says that MAE is robust to outliers but MSE is not and MSE can hamper the model if errors are too huge.
My question is that MSE and MAE both are error matrices,our priority is to just minimise the error whether we use MSE or MAE.Where does outliers come into play while using error matrices?

What difference can an error matrix make in linear regression for choosing optimal values of the parameters(in regards to outliers because as per my knowledge error matrices doesn't contribute for choosing parameters, its the loss function we are minimising) which we are trying to learn (y=mx+c : parameters being m and c)?

But if they are not helping with parameters then why are we worried about outliers while choosing error matrixes ?

Comment: No cross posting please https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/582238/mae-vs-mse-for-linear-regression/582254#582254

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is more reasonable to talk about error vectors not matrices in most cases. You have a vector is errors, only one column.

The parameters "m" and "c" in iyour example depends on the errors. Eventually they'll be picked in  a way minimizing your cost function. They'll be different for MSE and MAE. The first one will try to make a mistake on outliers better.

Here I'm talking mostly about cost function but expect something similar for them in role of metrics as well.

Example:

[image]

Here I create a 4 observations example. I use RMSE for comparision because MSE gives squared residuals, we want to get them back to the original non-squared scale at first.
The first 3 observations imply a very plain model y = 1 * x + 0. Then I compare it with the model y = 2*x using residuals

```
> tibble(x=1:4, y=c(1,2,3,8)) %>% 
+     {plot(.$x, .$y); .} %>% 
+     mutate(base_pred=x * 1) %>% 
+     mutate(outl_pred=x * 2) %>% 
+     mutate(across(ends_with('pred'), ~abs(. - y), 
        .names='{str_remove(col, "_pred")}_resi')) %>% 
+     print() %>% 
+     rename_with(~str_remove(., '_resi')) %>% 
+     summarise(across(c(base, outl), list(
+         mae=~mean(.),
+         rmse=~sqrt(mean(. ^ 2))))) %>% 
+     select(ends_with('mae'), everything())

      x     y base_pred outl_pred base_resi outl_resi
  <int> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1     1         1         2         0         1
2     2     2         2         4         0         2
3     3     3         3         6         0         3
4     4     8         4         8         4         0

  base_mae outl_mae base_rmse outl_rmse
     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1        1      1.5         2      1.87
```

You may see that base_model is better if you use MAE. Otherwise y=x*2 gives you better metric with RMSE  because it suffers more  and is more focused on outliers.